# r extract webdata need login

Tags: r, authentication, web-scraping, passwords

I want to download the table in this website,but it needs login.

`url <- "http://www.zh818.com/view.aspx?id=11798268"
library(httr)
GET(url, authenticate("username", "password"))`

it does not work.

If a login in chrome,can I use R to extract data directly?

Comment: I use `RSelenium` for webscraping a website with unsuported login. Only it is a bit more difficult to setup

Comment: Yes , I use RSelenium.
`> remDr$open()
[1] "Connecting to remote server"

Selenium message:Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: WIN8_1
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'
System info: host: 'uno', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver`

Comment: I think you need to do some more research on this. I started with this blog: https://www.r-bloggers.com/scraping-with-selenium/ I run a docker for chrome on a linux server, to connect to with RSelenium.